# What is "value" and "storageDepositLimit" in contract call?

Tags: smart-contract

After I called a `contract`, this is the extrinsic I found in the block:

[image]

What do these fields mean: `value`, `storageDepositLimit` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All those fields are arguments that were passed to the `contracts.call` extrinsic. The place to look for a description of these arguments is either the rustdoc on of the `pallet-contracts` within substrate or the metadata generated from the runtime containing the pallet-contracts. Unfortunately, the UI doesn't seem to show the description text of those arguments.

The rust doc of the `call` extrinsic can be found [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_contracts/pallet/enum.Call.html#variant.call).

`value`: It is the amount of native chain balance that is to be transferred as part of the `call` extrinsic. This is different from any value hold in the contract logic itself.

`storageDepositLimit`: The `pallet-contracts` uses something called automatic storage deposits where it will charge a deposit from callers in proportion to how much storage a transaction adds to the chain. This argument is for the caller to limit the amount of deposit that can be charged. Think of it as a gas limit but for storage. More information [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10082).